# Roomba iRobot Create 2 Open Interface, is there a way to turn off vacuum motor while the robot is docking?

Tags: irobot-create

I am able to control every desired aspect of my robot, except for vacuum motor which seems to be turned on for some reason every time I send `Seek Dock` (code `143`) command. Is there a way to turn it off? I was trying to send `Motors` (`138`) command with argument `0` after sending `Seek Dock`, but docking also means changing OI mode to `Passive` and `Motors` are not accepted in passive.

I would also like to understand the rationale behind having vacuum motor turned on during docking.

Comment: why are you not asking this at a roomba specific forum?

Comment: When I was looking for answers for my problems related to development for Roomba, most of them I found here. So I was assuming this space plays a role of such a forum?

Answer (score 2):

The vacuum is turned on while docking because during normal cleaning missions the robot avoids getting too close to the dock in an effort not to bump it or move it.  So the area close to the dock doesn't get cleaned and dirt and debris can still build up on the dock.  We want to clean the dock because dirty contacts can cause problems with charging.

*Disclaimer: I work at iRobot where I am developing the next generation of consumer robots. However, my postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.*